# Automatically fit text in a fixed height container

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5, fittextjs

How can I make my text automatically resize taking container height and width both into account ? I know that there are a few questions like this one but none of them seems to address me. i have tried fitText but it is just not taking the height of container into account and the text is flowing out of the container at a certain point.
Here is a piece of code:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 ms-3 mt-2 video-text-box bg-primary" style="height: 33vh">
        <h4 class="desc-heading">
            We offer a broad range of benefits.
        </h4>
        <p class="desc-text">
               You can <span class="fw-bold">customize</span> a benefits program that's exactly right for your personal solution.
        </p>
        <p class="desc-text">
               If you do not enroll, you and your family will not have benefit coverage beginning January 1, 2023.
        </p>
    </div>
```

fitText Code:

```
    jQuery(".desc-heading").fitText(1);
    jQuery(".desc-text").fitText(1.3);
```

Note:
Adjusting compressor to a greater value makes the text very small at tablet width.

Comment: I note the warning on http://fittextjs.com/  that this is not suitable (actually, it says don't you dare) for paragraph elements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so what do you think is a possible fix ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by double-wrapping the text + custom JS function. More details on why you need to take the width in consideration would be helpful though.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#btn_fit_text').on('click', function () {
    fit_text();
  });

});


function fit_text() {
        
    var $outer = $('.outer-container'),
            $inner = $('.inner-container'),
        font_size = parseInt($('.inner-container').css('font-size'));
    
    font_size = Number.isNaN(font_size) ? 16 : font_size;
    
    var is_oversize = $inner.outerHeight() > $outer.outerHeight();
    
    while (is_oversize) {
    
        font_size = parseInt($('.inner-container').css('font-size'));
        is_oversize = $inner.outerHeight() > $outer.outerHeight();
      
      $('.inner-container').css('font-size', (font_size - 1) + 'px');
    
        } 
    
    console.log('SIZE');
    console.log(font_size);
    
}
```

```css
.outer-container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-container {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="btn_fit_text">
Fit text
</button>

<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet condimentum neque, at porttitor justo. Nunc tellus nulla, egestas et vehicula et, malesuada non libero. Aliquam at libero ipsum. Sed rhoncus augue magna. Nunc bibendum ut purus ut blandit. Nullam pellentesque sapien et tempus hendrerit. Ut eget odio est. Proin ac tempor sapien. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually don't want to consider the width because anyways the text won't overflow horizontally. I just need it to stop overflowing vertically. Let me give it a try !!